# Can I use FormView with jQuery ajax to bind data?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, .net-4.5

What I want to do is this:
I prevent FormView from binding data when page loads,but when button clicked I'll fire event to bind FormView using ajax.
Is this possible in .NET 4.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Binding takes place at the server.  A FormView is a Server control.  So, no.

You could use an UpdatePanel to avoid a full page refresh, but many developers look on the UpdatePanel with disdain.

You could use one of the many jQuery libraries ([jsRender](http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2011/12/01/goodby-jquery-templates-hello-jsrender.aspx) is one) to populate an html table using jquery.